# Django: image tag expected an Image object, got <ImageFieldFile: profile_pics/file_x.jpg>

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm rendering the photo of a user in a Django/Wagtail template.

I've rendered other images in other Wagtail pages, all of them uploaded through the Wagtail Admin page.

However, this time I need to render on a Wagtail Page model from a Profile that asks for a photo when user signs up.

in the HTML I'm using:

```
{% image page.user.profile.photo fill-150x150 as post_img %}
<a href="{{ post.url }}">
  <img src="{{ post_img.url }}" class="mr-3" alt="{{ post_img.alt }}">
</a>
```

But getting this error:

[image]

If I delete that part, the template render ok, of course without the photo.

[image]

**Wagtail model:**

```
class PastorPage(Page):

    template = 'ministros/pastor_page.html'

    user = models.ForeignKey( 
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        related_name="+",
        on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user),

    )


    content = StreamField(
        [
            ("title_and_text", blocks.TitleAndTextBlock(classname='text_and_title')),
            ("full_richtext", blocks.RichtextBlock()),
            ("simple_richtext", blocks.SimpleRichtextBlock()),
            ("cards", blocks.CardBlock()),
            ("cta", blocks.CTABlock()),
        ],
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('content'),
        FieldPanel('user'),
    ]


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Pastor'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Pastores'
```

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests that the `photo` field on profile is a django `ImageField` rather than a wagtail image - which is what the `{% image %}` template tag. You'll need to either not use wagtail's image tag - or change the model to use a foreign key to wagtail image